# Java Robot class working in laptop but not pc

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

This is my first question to stackoverflow. Helped me a lot in the past whenever i was stuck. Anyway here is the problem:

I was using Java Robot in my PC. Everything was fine like i could type in notepad move mouse around in other applications like games etc. But there was only this one game which the java Robot did not work on. Nothing was detected on this game not even mouse movement. I tried to do some research on this and came to a conclusion that maybe that game has some sort of anti-bot system. Keep in mind this was in my PC which is windows 7 64bit. Then i thought to use the same code in my laptop(which is also windows 7 64bit) on the same game and it WORKED!

So my question is why did this happen? Why did it work in my laptop and not my PC?

here is the code:

```
package test_bot1;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class test_BOT1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Robot bot = new Robot();
            bot.delay(3000);
            bot.mouseMove(500, 0);

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            }
            bot.delay(100);
            bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            bot.delay(100);
            bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            bot.delay(200);
            bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            bot.delay(159);
            bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
            bot.delay(179);
            bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

K Out!

Comment: An empty catch block is a very bad idea.

Comment: Are they using the same version of Java?

Comment: @mabbas I just did this for testing to see how the Robot works.

Comment: yes they r using same version of java

Comment: *"I just did this for testing"*  It's not a good test if the code ignores output.  Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: i did change it and there are no errors. It is working but not on one game. When i focus on that game the Java Robot does not work but there are no errors either, this is in PC. When i use the same code in my laptop on the same game then it works

Answer (score 1):

Surely the simple answer to this is not to cheat at games?

Try adding e.printStackTrace() to your catch block and look to see if there are errors on the pc version and not on the laptop.

Comment: Well, i disagree with your simple answer. I think, if you program something to help you out in a game its first nice to learn new stuff for programming, and also nice for yourself because you automated stuff you would do with your mouse. For example in EVE Online, there is an build in autopilot, which isn't really good. Its better if you fly yourself. I've programmed an autopilot which simulates the flight i'd do by mouse. I saved 1,2 min per jump. And I learned stuff.

Comment: @Glen Lamb: I tried e.printStackTrace() in my PC but no error was given and no I am not making anything for cheating in games. Just want to understand it properly by messing around with it.

Comment: @Loki: I agree with you about automation.

I just found out about Java Robot and went crazy with it. I am messing around with it as much as I can to understand it properly. So I came across this problem.

Comment: hmm, maybe you need to try System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()); as standard err might not be going to your terminal. You are running from  a terminal I assume?

Comment: I am using NetBeans. Tried System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()); but still no error.